# Travelling to the US for independent research with VWP

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I am planning to come to the US for a period of 5 weeks to conduct independent research as visiting scholar in a University.
I will not receive any payment, and travel and accomodation expenditures will be covered by my home university (outside US).
Is it sufficient the VWP or do I need another kind of visa?
During the interview if the CBP ask me which kind of business I am going to undertake, is it sufficient to answer "independent research"?
thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be fine.  That's a bit too short for an answer, which is why I'm posting it as a comment.  Perhaps someone else can think of more to say.

Comment: You might get a better answer on [academia.se]. However, this is the sort of question that your university and the university you're visiting should both be able to give you a proper answer to. If CBP refuse you entry, you won't be able to use VWP again and will need a visa every time you visit the US.

Comment: Thus, ESTA should be enough to be admitted, without asking for any other kind of VISA, am I right?
thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Visa Waiver Program permits the same activities as a B visitor visa (B1 or B2).

The sort of short term independent research you propose is covered under B1 status and is [explicitly listed](https://jp.usembassy.gov/visas/faq-list/b1-b2-visas/) as an example of a permitted activity by the US Embassy Japan (and likely many other places).